# OpenVPN can connect, Traffic works but I am not in the Local Network

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, lan, openvpn

I have installed OpenVPN via PiVPN Script on my Raspberry Pi. Nearly Everything works fine. I can connect to it and my traffic passes my VPN-Server. My only problem is that I am not in my Local Network. So I cannot connect to it via ssh which was a reason why I installed OpenVPN. On my IPhone I can connect to the shell with termius without any problems. 
I am using Manjaro Linux on my notebook.

OpenVPN Version: 2.4.0

I hope s.o. has an Idee. If you need any output just ask me.

Thanks in advance,

HH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by changing the client configuration of OpenVPN. Now it makes sense why my vpn worked when I was using my mobile phone.

Comment: What did you change?

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't solved the problem yet. Check where your connection has problems.

1. I'd first ping into the server with `ping <local ip of the server>`. If you can ping to your server, you're virtually in your local network. If that doesn't work, you need to add route. Please [check this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893775/cant-ssh-to-server-with-vpn-connection) for that. But I don't think your problem is here.
2. Try `ssh -v <server>`, if it stops at `debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY`
   . You need to solve a small bug about encryption. Simply add this line to your `.ssh/config` file:

   ```
   KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp521
   ```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274274/specifying-ssh-kexalgorithms-works-at-cli-but-not-via-ssh-config

Comment: This solved my problem which seems to have been caused by some OpenVPN MTU negotiation bug related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229456/ssh-fails-with-connection-timed-out-in-vpn-and-hangs-here-expecting-ssh2-msg. For command line, `-oKexAlgorithms=ecdh-sha2-nistp521` to set it once.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone, who has

```
debian openvpn debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

should adjust the openvpn configuration and add  (nano /etc/openvpn/server.conf)

```
#Set Local Server MTU on TUN/TAP
tun-mtu 1492
mssfix 1400
#Set REMOTE Client MTU on TUN/TAP
push "tun-mtu 1492"
push "mssfix 1400"
```

### Previous issue:

this fixed the problem for me as using `ssh -vvvv` did tell that the connect was successfull, but hangs on that point - after using tcpdump and wireguard, i figured this point out - and then applied. works for now.

### A word After:

Remind, that it could also be needed, to lower 1492  by steps of minus 8 (1byte equals 8 bit) that is the reason why -8

PUSH has the nice feature, that you dont need to take care about any client!

If you find it usefule, leave an upvote on me ;-)